# How to solve simple this algebra re-arrangement

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation:

$$(r+1)h_3=r\cdot h_1+h_2$$

In the solution for the question, the next line simply says "Solved for r" and then states:

$$r=\frac{h_3-h_2}{h_1-h_3}$$

I have tried to write this out as many ways as I can to isolate 'r' but nothing is working. Whenever I remove a a term from one side of the equation it just ends up complicating the other.

Would someone please be able to, step-by-step in detail, show me how to go from the first equation to the second please?

Comment: hint: a(b+c) = ab + ac

Answer (score 1):

$(r+1)h_3 = rh_1 + h_2$

$\Rightarrow rh_3 + h_3 = rh_1 +h_2$

Subtracting $rh_1 + h_3$ from both sides of the equation

$\Rightarrow rh_3 - rh_1 = h_2 - h_3$

Since $r$ is a common factor on the left hand side

$\Rightarrow r(h_3 - h_1) = h_2 - h_3$

$\Rightarrow r = \frac{h_2 - h_3}{h_3-h_1}=\frac{h_3 - h_2}{h_1-h_3}$

Comment: Can you please elaborate between the second and third steps?

Comment: @david_10001 What don't you understand about it?

Comment: It's ok, I worked out what was going on. I'm having one of those days were nothing makes sense all of a sudden. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @david_10001 I made some changes, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

$(r + 1)h_3 = rh_1 + h_2$

Factor out the $r$ on the left hand side
$$rh_3+h_3=rh_1 +h_2$$

Subtract $rh_1$ and $h_3$ from both sides

$$rh_3-rh_1 = h_2-h_3$$

Divide by $(h_3-h_1)$

$$r= \frac{h_2-h_3}{h_3-h_1}$$